# EXCEL If cell in sheet1 equals specified value, populate the members name in sheet2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm new to excel and am having trouble finding a function that will allow me to do this:

I am trying to get the members name to auto populate in sheet2 if their TSC equals the specified value(For instance "K" or "M". So if the members TSC is changed to K in sheet1 then in sheet2 their name will automatically appear under the Training Status Code section for that letter.

I've been trying to use the IF function to do this. This is what I have:

```
=IF(Sheet1!F:F = "M", Sheet1!A:A,"")
```

In the attached screenshot you can see that for training status code M Garcia has populated but no other name has, I don't understand why its doing that. I also specified the cells so F5:F10 and A5:A10 but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Does anyone know how to solve this or a better way to approach this?

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcEdI.png)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaNak.png)

Also, I'm using excel 2016!

Comment: How much data are we talking?  In Office 365 we have Filter which would do this easily.  But with 2016 you are stuck with array type formula and as such too much data would bog things down and vba would be a better alternative.

Comment: I unfortunately don’t have the option of using office 365. There’s about 100 members that it would have to look through for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Sheet1!F:F="M")*ROW(Sheet1!F:F),ROW(1:1))),"")`

This formula indexes column A of Sheet1 where the smallest row number of column F in Sheet1 equals `M`.
If you drag it down `ROW` will behave as a counter for the Nth smallest match.

You need to enter this array-formula using `ctrl+shift+enter`

Comment: Thank you! This worked flawlessly. I would never have come to this myself.